# BitCode enable clashes with different libraries/frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I am having `GoogleSignIn.framwork` and `Parse.framework` in my project.

If I enable bitcode, I get this:

```
GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
```

If I disable it, I get many errors for `Parse.framework` regarding `sqlite_column_name` and many more.

```
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:


      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnNameToIndexMap] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)


  "_sqlite3_column_name", referenced from:


      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult columnNameToIndexMap] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)


  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:


      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult dataForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)


  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:


      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult intForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)


     (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_column_int)


  "_sqlite3_bind_null", referenced from:


      -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)


  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:


      -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)


     (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_bind_double)


  "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count", referenced from:


      -[PFSQLiteDatabase _executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:cachingEnabled:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)


  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:


      ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)


      -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)


     (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_bind_text)


  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:


      ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)


      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult doubleForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)


     (maybe you meant: _fbsdkdfl_sqlite3_column_double)


  "_sqlite3_clear_bindings", referenced from:


      ___34-[PFDateFormatter dateFromString:]_block_invoke in Parse(PFDateFormatter.o)


  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:


      -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult stringForColumnIndex:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.o)
```

How I can fix it.

I have updated both frameworks.

Comment: Disable it and try build->clean. I am using Parse framework without bit code, no issue

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: It looks like you haven't included libsqlite3. Are you using parse from a pod file?